# Always hitting the exception

Tags: python

Currently doing some python things, I can't use any imports.

I'm making a connect 4 game and for some reason I keep hitting the exception on the below code. I've changed some things to ints rather than their variables so you can see what I'm putting in.
No matter what number gets put into that I always hit "Invalid column"

```py
def play():
    while (True):
        try:
            drawfield(currentField)
            print(f"Players turn: {Player}")
            columnSelect = int(input("Select your column: "))
            if columnSelect >= 0 and columnSelect <= 13:
                for i in range(11):
                    if currentField[columnSelect][i] != " ":
                        locate = i - 1
                mark(columnSelect, locate)
            else:
                raise print("outside board")
            break
        except:
            print("Invalid column")
             except:
                 print("Invalid column")
```

The error I get is index out of range.
The list is:

```
currentField = [[" "," "," "," "," "," "],[" "," "," "," "," "," "],[" "," "," "," "," "," "],[" "," "," "," "," "," "],[" "," "," "," "," "," "],[" "," "," "," "," "," "],[" "," "," "," "," "," "]]
```

Comment: `except:` will accept all the Exceptions,remove `try..except` to see your exception directly.

Comment: One exception that the bare `except` could be masking is that the name `Player` referenced in the first `print` is undefined.

Comment: try use instead of just `except`, `except Exception as e: print(e)`,
so you know what kind of exception you are getting first

Comment: What error are you getting? Also, to make your code more readable, please place it between 3 backticks ``.

Comment: I removed the except which did show the index error, however it's not out of index range.

Comment: It could be easier to have to code in correct format. But it looks like you didn't defined your variables in play() => currentField, Player,... But As other said, try to run your code without the try, except in first.

Comment: Thank you for that,if currentField[columnSelect][i] != " " and i < 11:
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: And what is the format of currentField ? A list of list (14x12)?

Comment: I've edited the post to show the list

Comment: You have 6 sublists but your range is 0 thru 9. `for i in range(11): if currentField[columnSelect][i] != " ":`. So `i` will be out of range after the 6th item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things to improve the game:

- As the comments and other answer mentioned, be sure to stay in the array\list length when setting values. It's helpful to use `len(mylist)` instead of hard coding the length.
- Try\Except is not really useful unless you can recover from the error (or log it). In this case, just let the error happen so you can see the issue.
- When checking for an open space in the board, start from the bottom and find the first empty cell.
- Consider that a column may be full so the new piece cannot be added.

I used this code for testing:

```
currentField = [
   [" "," "," "," "," "," "],
   [" "," "," "," "," "," "],
   [" "," "," "," "," "," "],
   [" "," "," "," "," "," "],
   [" "," "," "," "," "," "],
   [" "," "," "," "," "," "],
   [" "," "," "," "," "," "]]
   
def drawfield():
   for x in range(len(currentField[0])):
      for y in range(len(currentField)):
         print("|" + currentField[y][x], end="")
      print("|")
      
def mark(x, y, p): 
   currentField[x][y] = p  # update field with player

def play():
    Player = 'X'  # player is X or O
    while (True):
        drawfield()
        print(f"Players turn: {Player}")
        columnSelect = int(input("Select your column: "))
        if columnSelect >= 0 and columnSelect <= 6:  # can also use len(currentField)
            locate = 0
            for i in range(5,-1,-1):  # start from bottom, find first empty cell
                if currentField[columnSelect][i] == " ":
                    locate = i
                    mark(columnSelect, locate, Player) # update field
                    break # found cell, loop is done
            else:  # no empty cells
               print("Column is full")
            Player = 'X' if Player == 'O' else 'O'  # swap players
        else:
            print("outside board")              
play()
```

Output during play

```
| | | | | | | |
| | | | | | | |
| | | | | | | |
| | |O|X| | | |
| | |X|O|X| | |
| | |O|X|O| |X|
Players turn: O
Select your column:
```

Answer (score 1):

`currentField` has only 6 columns and the range is checked for 11, so for the `currentField` size, check the range till 5 (includes Zero index so total length will be 6).
Similarly `currentField` has 7 Rows but checked for 13, it should be checked for 6.

```py
for i in range(5):
if columnSelect >= 0 and columnSelect <= 13:
```

Or else update the `currentField` to match the size of 12x14.

Comment: Oh my.....it was right in my face i used the board width rather than practical board.